# Swift 4.2 - Alamofire all of a sudden not working

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 4.7 with Swift 4.2 and ever since converting my code to Swift 4.2 Alamofire all of sudden does not work at all.

I have a simple call like so:

```
func createUser(username: String, email: String, password: String, passwordConfirm: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void)
    {

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "username" : username,
            "email" : email,
            "password" : password,
            "confirm_password" : passwordConfirm
        ]

        Alamofire.request(webservice + "?action=register", method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in

            if(response.error == nil)
            {

                if let result = response.result.value {

                    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                    if(jsonData["response"] == nil)
                    {
                        completion("")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completion(jsonData["response"] as! String)
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                completion((response.error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }

        }
    }
```

All the parameter are getting populated properly, after checking my api, its call the correct method (?action=register) but my post is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried chucking your URL in something like Postman to see if the API you're hitting is kicking anything back?

Comment: Yes I did...and I used Postman, it is returning what is expected.

Comment: Another thought would be to clean caches (perhaps close Xcode, nuke derived data from the command line) and re-open the project. Another thought would be to update your CocoaPods/Carthage/whatever in case something quirky happened with the automated 4.2 Swift update. The latest [Alamofire is 4.7.3](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases) looks like a Swift 4.2 update.

Comment: have you tried restart you laptop after convert?

Comment: you do not get any parameters in the backend, which is sent by the client. Is it the problem you are facing ?

Comment: plz share error you are getting by printing response.error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know you can parse JSON super easily with Swift 4.2?
I used it recently with a dialling code table view - the data was a local JSON file:

```
    struct Countries: Codable {
    let countries: [Country]
}

struct Country: Codable {
    let code: Int
    let name: String
    let flagImage: String
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case code
    case name
    case flagImage
}

class CountryListVC: UITableViewController {

    func loadJSON() {

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "countryDiallingCodes", ofType: "json") {

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
                let jsonObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(Countries.self, from: data)
                print("JSON Object: ", jsonObj)
                countries = jsonObj.countries

            } catch let error {
                print (error)
            }
        } else {
            print ("Error in path")
        }
    }
```